# codeigniter, zend-framework which is better

Tags: zend-framework, codeigniter

We are starting new project in php. That is used for pyroll.
In codeigniter and zend-framework which is the better option.

Comment: Do you know either framework?

Answer (score 2):

This question is related to the following question that might help you :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648/what-php-framework-would-you-choose-for-a-new-application-and-why

Take a look......

Answer (score 0):

What ever frameworks you use, its the role of developer to make sure the app will work perfect.
Its your choice than counting the fans of each community for its being developed by you than me :-) . Look both, and finally the choice it yours.